# How to apply a mask over a png image excluding the transparent Part in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, image-manipulation

I want a greenish tint over the non transparent part of the image, a tried searching for an image manipulation library so that i can manipulate the image directly but couldn't find

Comment: see [Image.color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/color.html) property

Answer (score 0):

Use a container for the image

```
Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
              image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2)),
                image: new NetworkImage(
                  'Imgurl',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```